# kotlin-native: missing SDL.h when building sample tetris app on Windows via MSYS2

Tags: kotlin, sdl-2, kotlin-native

I have a 64 bit system with windows 7. I built kotlin-native via `gradlew dist distPlatformLibs` then entered a msys2 terminal and via pacman installed the mingw sdl2 lib. Via winpty I execute the Tetris sample app's `build.bat` and get the following compilation exception:

```
$ winpty ./build.bat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4397933690362265283.c:1:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.UtilsKt.ensureNoCompileErrors(Utils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.IndexerKt.indexDeclarations(Indexer.kt:902)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.IndexerKt.buildNativeIndexImpl(Indexer.kt:892)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.indexer.NativeIndexKt.buildNativeIndex(NativeIndex.kt:56)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.processCLib(main.kt:284)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.interop.gen.jvm.MainKt.interop(main.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.InteropCompilerKt.invokeInterop(InteropCompiler.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.main(main.kt:29)
```

Disabling `@echo off` in the script I can see the above exception happens during the call to `call cinterop -def ".\src\main\c_interop\sdl.def" -compilerOpts "-I\msys64\mingw64\include\SDL2" -target "mingw" -o sdl || exit /b`

Comment: Does it build via `build.bat`? Run with debug output so you can see all the commands logged.

Comment: Above is output of `build.bat`. I have updated question with what command generates the exception specifically.

Comment: Obviously begs the question... is SDL.h in \msys64\mingw64\include\SDL2?

Comment: I should have seen that what with the comment telling me the requirement and all... Can you help me some more with the compilation error I now get above?

Comment: @Strelok forget that, I've created a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075105/getting-lots-of-sdl-inferred-type-is-x-but-ux-expected-when-building-kotlin-na

Comment: If you want to answer this question with SDL.h isn't being found I'll mark it as correct.